# new image in update form didn't change

Tags: php, laravel

I made an update form wherein in i can edit and update current uploads in my renting shop project.
but i've been having this problem wherein the image isn't changing both in the page and database, but when i checked the storage/public/images it stores the same current image whenever i try to try again.

but the rest in my form is working fine and already changeable except the image.

Here is in my CarsController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $car = Car::find($id);

    $car->car_brand = $request->car_brand;
    $car->car_name = $request->car_name;
    $car->description = $request->description;
    $car->car_type_id = $request->car_type_id;

    if ($request->hasFile('image_location')) {
        Storage::disk('public')->delete($car->image_location); // remove the old file.
        $path = $request->image_location->store('images', 'public'); // save the new image.
        $car->image_location = $path;
    }

    $car->save();
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'The item has been updated.');

    return redirect('/selections');

}
```

Here's the form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image_location" required>
</div>
```

i don't know what could possibly wrong. anyone please enlighten me. Thanks in advance. Anyway the migrated column name is image_location

also here's in my store()

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $car = new car;

    $car->car_brand = $request->car_brand;
    $car->car_name = $request->car_name;
    $car->description = $request->description;
    $car->car_type_id = $request->car_type_id;

    $path = $request->image_location->store('images', 'public');
    $car->image_location = $path;
    $car->availability = $request->availability;

    $car->save();
    $request->session()->flash('message', 'The item has been added.');

    return redirect('/selections');
}
```

Comment: can you please post the create method?

Comment: create() in the contollers? its empty, i put it in index() since i use modal in my page or do you mean store()

Comment: yeah sorry, the method where you receive the data and CREATE a new element

Comment: that's okay and i already edited my question and posted my store() thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your code works perfectly for me.

You could try adding some log lines and see where the problem lies:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

```
if ($request->hasFile('image_location')) {
    Log::debug('File has been found in request.');

    // Check if the old car image exists.
    Log::debug($car->image_location . (Storage::disk('public')
            ->exists($car->image_location)? ' exists': ' does not exist'));

    Storage::disk('public')->delete($car->image_location); // Remove the old file.

    // Check if the old car image (if it existed) has been deleted.
    Log::debug($car->image_location . (Storage::disk('public')
            ->exists($car->image_location)? ' exists': 'does not exist'));

    $path = $request->image_location->store('images', 'public'); // save the new image.

    // Check if the new file has been saved correctly.
    Log::debug($path . (Storage::disk('public')
        ->exists($path)? ' exists': 'does not exist'));

    $car->image_location = $path;
}
```

After uploading a new image, my `storage/logs/laravel.log` shows:

```
[2019-12-28 10:18:03] local.DEBUG: File has been found in request.  
[2019-12-28 10:18:03] local.DEBUG: images/WPMkdG56f4YXsd3IUJ3Ar1DbXF0QmtDz9bs0lKoI.gif exists
[2019-12-28 10:18:03] local.DEBUG: images/WPMkdG56f4YXsd3IUJ3Ar1DbXF0QmtDz9bs0lKoI.gif does not exist
[2019-12-28 10:18:03] local.DEBUG: images/s9RtTdFSv0Is8AgxDWX5c09zG8SyU987RVeC0di5.gif exists
```